# Import JPEG Fails

Tags: bugs, import, image, kernel, crash

**Bug introduced in 11.0.0 and persists through 11.0.1**

---

I have a set of .jpg files that not only fail `Import[]` but also crash the kernel.  Sample file [here](https://s3.amazonaws.com/com.widelane.tmp/00048000.jpg).

There is no diagnostic output from `Import[]`, nothing.  I just get the terminal "beep" and the kernel dies.  The files open fine in Preview etc so I don't think they are corrupt.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: It also crashes my kernel when I drag and drop it into a notebook, though I do get the (uninformative) message: "The kernel Local has quit (exited) during the course of an evaluation."

Comment: `Import["https://s3.amazonaws.com/com.widelane.tmp/00048000.jpg"]` does no harm for me.

Comment: As a work-around, you can load it into photoshop, save as a .png and then it imports OK. I'm guessing there is some kind of metadata that Mathematica isn't expecting and this gets stripped out when resaving.

Comment: On my Mac `Import` failed but Mathematica did not quit or crash. The following worked 1) On web site "Copy image", 2) open "Preview" and "File | New from Clipboard", 3) "Save..." to local file as JPEG, 4) `Import` local  .jpg file

Comment: It's quite obviously a bug, so please do report it to Wolfram support. (I can confirm the crash with M11.0.1 on OS X.)

Comment: Ok, I'll go file a bug.  Thanks everyone!

Comment: @corey979 btw, I get a 403 (forbidden) when trying to import the s3 URL.

Comment: works with 10.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is clearly a bug, so please remember to report it to [Wolfram](http://support.wolfram.com/).

You have many of these files so you need some workaround for an *automated* import.  One way is to process the image through the `jpegtran` utility.  It reads and writes from/to pipes, so something like this will work:

```
Import["!/opt/local/bin/jpegtran 00048000.jpg", "JPEG"]
```

I have `jpegtran` installed at the above location on OS X (through MacPorts), and I gave the full path. Use the correct location on your machine. Note the `!` in the `Import` line: this tells `Import` to run the program and read its output instead of reading from a file.

Comment: fantastic!  I have thousands of these files to import.

Answer (score 7):

The bug is in reading Exif metadata. A workaround is to use `IncludeMetaInformation -> None` option:

```
Import["https://s3.amazonaws.com/com.widelane.tmp/00048000.jpg", 
IncludeMetaInformation -> None]
```